# What does "wonky talk" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link but I still can't understand it: 
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wonky?q=wonky
"This isn't just some wonky talk either. Low inflation plays out in a very real way."

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/10/19/news/economy/inflation-economy-mystery/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Comment: I'd say that "wonky talk" means here "idle chatter", just speculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's another rather unused word and it's polysemous, which means it has several different meanings.  It can mean "unsteady or unstable/shaky"; it can mean "crooked"; it can mean "not functioning correctly"; in your instance, from the context clues, it most likely means "crazy or mentally unstable".  "Wonky talk" is "crazy talk".

***NOTE:*** Oxford apparently doesn't give you all of the possible definitions; it just gives you one definition.

P.S. I have been informed that this may be being used as the adjective of "wonk", which is similar to a nerd (it's a person who studies a lot and has no life).  In English, it's very seldom that we would use "wonky" as an adjective for "wonk"; we'd use it as a replacement for the obsolete adjective "wankle" with some of the definitions I've given you above.  To use it to mean "of or relating to a wonk" would confuse a lot of native speakers like me, who are used to hearing it mean "out of whack", "crazy", "feeble or unsteady".  For example:

"Donald Trump is now the President of the United States.  Has this whole country gone **wonky**?  Is the system using the electoral college rather than the popular vote outdated and **wonky**?"

Now, I voted for Donald Trump, so I wouldn't ever say this; however, I have heard statements similar to this using "wonky".  It's a weird way of saying everything is backwards or off-kilter.  If I were trying to talk about how a wonk speaks, I would say,

"That's a bunch of wonk talk"

or

"That's a bunch of nerd talk";

I would never say,

"That's wonky talk."

Comment: +1 But note that it in this particular context it might also mean "characteristic of wonks"--expert jargon which laypersons cannot distinguish from meaningless doublespeak.

Comment: Yes, that's another meaning. I hadn't read the article before answering, so I just used context clues. Yes, "of or relating to a wonk" has the adjective "wonky".  A wonk is like a nerd---someone who studies a lot. It's a bad word to use therein because it is a rarely-used polysemous word, meaning we don't use it often and it has several meanings based upon context.

Comment: **wonkish** would probably have been a better choice to refer to the jargon of economic policy wonks.